# ABRT report says "irq 19: nobody cared", but why?

Tags: kernel, boot, abrt

Every couple weeks, I need to reboot my system. When I do, and enter as root in the terminal, the following message (in some variation) appears:

```
ABRT has detected 3 problem(s). For more info run: abrt-cli list --since 1440594093
```

I usually ignore it, but I decided to check it out. Entering the suggested command brings the following:

```
id cc91ff6c3e2e76eaf0956435836ad6d48d27bdb5
reason:         irq 19: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
time:           Thu 27 Aug 2015 01:40:39 PM EDT
cmdline:        BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/centos-root ro rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 rd.lvm.lv=centos/root crashkernel=auto vconsole.keymap=us rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
package:        kernel
count:          1
Directory:      /var/spool/abrt/oops-2015-08-27-13:40:39-663-0

id 35973446166ec36265e0c46ee2b2b553e759fdf0
reason:         irq 19: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
time:           Wed 26 Aug 2015 09:17:18 AM EDT
cmdline:        BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/centos-root ro rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 rd.lvm.lv=centos/root crashkernel=auto vconsole.keymap=us rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
Directory:      /var/spool/abrt/oops-2015-08-26-09:17:17-663-0
Reported:       cannot be reported

id 49915ba710ac612e102ac910313038528958afa3
reason:         irq 19: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
time:           Wed 26 Aug 2015 09:08:02 AM EDT
cmdline:        BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-229.1.2.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/centos-root ro rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 rd.lvm.lv=centos/root crashkernel=auto vconsole.keymap=us rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
package:        kernel
count:          4
Directory:      /var/spool/abrt/oops-2015-08-26-09:08:02-26725-0
```

Why am I getting these messages? I have not done any debugging because I do not know where to even start.

```
# Linux Kernel: 3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64
# CentOS Linux release: 7.1.1503 (Core)
```

Comment: "try booting with the "irqpoll" option" < do this

Comment: What does it do? Also, thank you for the edits :-)

Comment: The reason of the "try booting with the "irqpoll" option" message, is that the bug/crash cannot be determined because the proper verbosity isn't available. https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=7452

Comment: Does it affect my system at all? Or will it work like normal? (I do not want to enable a safe-mode type thing)

Comment: Depends... do you want to know why the message appears?

Comment: Yes I do.. I will restart in the morning before work when I have time. I will update my message accordingly.. I just need to figure out how to boot with a certain option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27511/discussion-between-hunter-stevens-and-braiam).